# How make font of desireable size?

Tags: java, fonts, awt, font-size

In which units font sizes are measured in Java? What if I want "A" letter of given dimensions, how to find appropriate font size?

Answer (score 3):

The font size is measured in points. [This is the number of pixels in the tallest character](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=5880.0). In most fonts, this will be pretty much the height of every capital letter. As far as dimensions go, the width will vary widely depending on the font you use.